# Groupby for datetime on a scale of hours (ignoring what day)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a series of floats with a datetimeindex that I have resampled into bins of 3 hours. As such I have an index containing

```
2015-01-01 09:00:00
2015-01-01 12:00:00
2015-01-01 15:00:00
2015-01-01 18:00:00
2015-01-01 21:00:00
2015-01-02 00:00:00
2015-01-02 03:00:00
2015-01-02 06:00:00
2015-01-02 09:00:00
```

and so forth. I am trying to sum the floats associated with each time of day, say 09:00:00, for all days.

The only way I can think to do it with my limited experience is to convert this series to a dataframe by using the date time index as another column, then running iterations to see if the hours slot of the date time is equal to one another than summing the values. I feel like this is horribly inefficient and probably not the 'correct' way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you just want to group datetime column into hour and minute aggregations

Comment: or just convert them to an actual `datetime.time` and reindex on that.

Comment: Yes I just want to group the datetime into hour aggregations. I think converting to datetime.time would work. Though I would need still need to convert the series into a dataframe right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [116]: s
Out[116]:
2015-01-01 09:00:00    3
2015-01-01 12:00:00    1
2015-01-01 15:00:00    0
2015-01-01 18:00:00    1
2015-01-01 21:00:00    0
2015-01-02 00:00:00    9
2015-01-02 03:00:00    2
2015-01-02 06:00:00    2
2015-01-02 09:00:00    7
2015-01-02 12:00:00    8
Freq: 3H, Name: val, dtype: int32

In [117]: s.groupby(s.index - s.index.normalize()).sum()
Out[117]:
00:00:00     9
03:00:00     2
06:00:00     2
09:00:00    10
12:00:00     9
15:00:00     0
18:00:00     1
21:00:00     0
Name: val, dtype: int32
```

or:

```
In [118]: s.groupby(s.index.hour).sum()
Out[118]:
0      9
3      2
6      2
9     10
12     9
15     0
18     1
21     0
Name: val, dtype: int32
```